# Trouble with media queries for specific mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I've been working on a page lately based on The Witcher lore, just to learn some concepts about web development and design, since I had some cool looking ideas and thought to give it a try and work on it. I've been working on media queries for responsiveness on the homepage but I can't seem to nail down the display on screens similar to Samsung Note 20 Ultra. I've tested the page on many different devices and it looks fine on the vast majority, but no matter what I've tried I cant seem to get the main "Chapters" div to be in the center of the screen for Note 20 Ultra and some other similarly-sized devices. I have used max-width queries for when resizing the window on my laptop, some conventional intervals I had people suggest me, and exact width and height for Note 20 Ultra and other devices that appear on Google Chrome's devtools in the inspector. On the devtools, the screen appears perfect for all the sizes I've made queries for, including the Note20Ultra display size, but when I open the page on my phone it looks nothing like it; the main transparent div appears very high up on the page and not in the center as the Chrome inspect window suggests.

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>The Modern Witcher's Journal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>




<!--<audio id="source" autoplay loop>
    <source src="C:\Users\user\AngularProjects\The ModernWitcher's Journal\audio\pages\home- 
page-theme.mp3">
</audio>-->



<div class="container">

    <br>
    <h1 class="homepage-title">
        <img src="images/witcher-transparent.png" alt="witcherLogo" 
        class="witcher-transparent-logo">
        The Modern Witcher's Journal
        <img src="images/witcher-transparent.png" alt="witcherLogo" 
        class="witcher-transparent-logo">
    </h1>
    <br>

    <div class="transparent-center-div">

        <br>
        <h2 class="sections-header">Chapters</h2>
        <br>

        <p class="sections-list">
            <button class="sections-list-buttons" id="bestiary" 
onClick="bestiaryClicked()">Bestiary</button>
            <br>
            <button class="sections-list-buttons" id="signs" onClick="signsClicked()">The 
Signs</button>
            <br>
            <button class="sections-list-buttons" id="alchemy" 
onclick="alchemyClicked()">Alchemy</button>
            <br>
            <button class="sections-list-buttons" id="map" onclick="mapClicked()">Map</button>
        </p>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And these are the CSS queries with the size conditions based on what i found online about display sizes of different large mobile devices. The last two ones are used for Note 20Ultra(normal display and flipped horizontally). I've had problems with some devices similarly to the situation I'm currently in with Note20(and other similar sized models), but I always found a way to fix them. I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your time.

```
@media screen and (width: 1080px) and (height: 2340px)
{
.container .transparent-center-div
{
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.342);
    color: rgb(228, 195, 5);
    border-radius: 1cm;
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
    margin-top: 60%;
    padding-top: 4cm;
    padding-bottom: 4cm;
    position: relative;
}

.sections-header
{
    font-size: 80px;
}

.sections-list-buttons
{
    font-size: 65px;
}

.homepage-title
{
    margin-top: 1cm;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.homepage-title .witcher-transparent-logo
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
}

@media screen and (width: 2316px) and (height: 1080px)
{
.container .transparent-center-div
{
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.342);
    color: rgb(228, 195, 5);
    border-radius: 1cm;
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding-top: 4cm;
    padding-bottom: 4cm;
    position: relative;
}

.sections-header
{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.sections-list-buttons
{
    font-size: 35px;
}

.homepage-title
{
    margin-top: 1cm;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.homepage-title .witcher-transparent-logo
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
}

@media screen and (width: 1080px) and (height: 2316px)
{
.container .transparent-center-div
{
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.342);
    color: rgb(228, 195, 5);
    border-radius: 1cm;
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
    margin-top: 60%;
    padding-top: 4cm;
    padding-bottom: 4cm;
    position: relative;
}

.sections-header
{
    font-size: 70px;
}

.sections-list-buttons
{
    font-size: 55px;
}

.homepage-title
{
    margin-top: 1cm;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.homepage-title .witcher-transparent-logo
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
}
```

View on inspect:
[image: inspect view]

View on mobile screen:
[image: view on mobile]

Comment: This might be a stretch but try reordering your media queries from narrowest to widest, going down the css page.

Comment: @wazz I tried this but it did not fix my problem, I still have the same issues

Answer (score 1):

In responsive design, there is a difference between a device's screen resolution and viewport size. A mobile device's screen resolution could be `1920x1080` but its viewport size (or CSS ratio) could be `736x414px`. This depends on the device. More info about viewport sizes [here](https://webspeedtools.com/viewport-vs-screen-resolution-vs-dpr-vs-ppi/) and [here](https://www.electricmayhemsolutions.net/screen-resolution-vs-viewport-responsive-web-design/).
When writing media queries in CSS for responsive design, you should use the viewport sizes. In your case, the Note20 Ultra's viewport size is [412x883px](https://yesviz.com/devices/samsung-note20-ultra/). So your media query's `max-width` should be for `883px` or the closest "common" resolution of `1024px`. You can test your site in the browser using these size too.

Couple of other points to note:

- In your code, the breakpoints are `width` and `height` instead of `max-width` or `max-height`. So they're probably not getting triggered in your mobile (the phone's navigation will reduce the screen height). It might work in your browser because you've used the exact pixel in the DevTools
- In responsive development, you will probably not need to use both height and width. You will generally use only `max-width` with common screen sizes as breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you for your response! And yeah the fixed width and heights are just out of desperation lol, I'll try following your advice next time